# Nuxt Plugins not working after build ( use apexchart )

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apexcharts

I use apex chart in nuxt
and apply plugins with my code
this working in dev mode

```
cross-env NODE_ENV=development HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=3000 nodemon server/index.js --watch server
```

but not working in build source

```
nuxt build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=80 node server/index.js
```

Here is my codes

plugins/vue-apexchar.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueApexCharts from 'vue-apexcharts'

Vue.component('VueApexCharts', VueApexCharts);
```

nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: [
    { src : '~/plugins/vue-apexchart.js', ssr : false },
],
build: {
  vendor : [
     'vue-apexchart'
  ]
}
```

weekChart.vue

```
<VueApexCharts max-width="300" type="area" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></VueApexCharts>
```

these codes working in dev mode but not working build files

I needs your helps for solve this problomes

Please Help me

Here is my source code > https://github.com/zoz0312/Nuxt_Blog

Comment: Hope this [issue](https://github.com/apexcharts/vue-apexcharts/issues/34#issuecomment-544191308) can help you :)

Comment: I solved this problem THANK YOU!!!!

Comment: I was happy to help :) Have a good day

Comment: You are having spelling mistake you file name is "vue-apexchar.js" but in plugin you put vue-apexchart.js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<client-only>
    <MY COMPONENT/>
</client-only>
```

Using 'client-only' tag solved this problem

"This component is used to purposely render a component only on client-side."
my plugins working only client-side so use that tags, I can Solved this problem